# Android Preference-Specific Permission Requests

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, android-calendar, android-permissions

Is there a way to request a specific permission only when the user enables a certain preference?

In my case, I have an option to sync with the calendar to add dates and set reminders (to my knowledge, you can't set reminders in the calendar with Intents). Obviously I need permission to access the calendar, but ONLY when the user enables this option. I'd like to, when the user enables the preference, request permission, then disable the option if permission isn't granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Unfortunately there is no option to do that.

`No checks with the user are done while an application is running: it either was granted a particular permission when installed, and can use that feature as desired, or the permission was not granted and any attempt to use the feature will fail without prompting the user.`

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

Answer (score 1):

This is possible since Marshmallow. See [video showing best practice to ask for permission from Android Marshmallow](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/index.html#android-marshmallow-60-asking-for-permission)

You can find snippets of code allowing you to do this at [Android developer guide to requesting permission for Marshmallow and above](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)